# How can I add an image to all pages of my PDF?

Tags: image, pdf, image-processing, razor, itext

I have been trying to add an image to all pages using itextsharp. The image needs to be OVER all content of every page. I have used the following code below all the other`doc.add()`

```
Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 30, 1);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/pdf/" + fname), FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();
Image image = Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/images/draft.png"));
image.SetAbsolutePosition(12, 300);
writer.DirectContent.AddImage(image, false);
doc.Close();
```

The above code only inserts an image in the last page. Is there any way to insert the image in the same way in all pages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's normal that the image is only added once; after all: you're adding it only once. (Or you've left away some essential steps in your code snippet: see the edit I made.)

In any case: you can solve your problem by using a page event. There are some examples in Java here: http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/events

Or you can consult chapter 5 of my book. All examples are available in [Java](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=5) as well as in [C#](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C05).

You should create a document in 5 steps and add an event in step 2:

```
// step 1
Document document = new Document();
// step 2
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
MyEvent event = new MyEvent();
writer.PageEvent = event;
// step 3
document.Open();
// step 4
// Add whatever content you want to add
// step 5
document.Close();
```

You have to write the `MyEvent` class yourself:

```
protected class MyEvent : PdfPageEventHelper {

    Image image;

    public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        image = Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/images/draft.png"));
        image.SetAbsolutePosition(12, 300);
    }

    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        writer.DirectContent.AddImage(image);
    }
}
```

The `OnEndPage()` in class `MyEvent` will be triggered every time the `PdfWriter` has finished a page. Hence the image will be added on every page.

**Caveat:** it is important to create the `image` object outside the `OnEndPage()` method, otherwise the image bytes risk being added as many times as there are pages in your PDF (leading to a bloated PDF).

Comment: Yes I did not put any code to add images to since I never found any way to do so.

Comment: i am using razor and i dont find an option to create file or override methods or to include an external c# file

Comment: Razor is using an obsolete, unsupported version of iTextSharp. It is not endorsed by iText Software. I'm sorry, but nobody at iText will be able to help you. You should contact the people responsible for Razor.

Comment: thank you. i have already added razor tags. I am checking if there is any way to include classes from a .cs file

Comment: thank you i found a way out in razor. I am not sure what you told is "obsolete and unsupported version", but I simply had to find a way to link a .cs file to razor. 

basically you need to save the .cs file in a folder called "App_Code" in the root

Comment: @Neville are you sure your edit works? It looks like you put a `PDFWatermark` constructor into a `MyEvent` class.

Comment: oops. PDFWatermark is the name of the class i had used instead of MyEvent. Thanks for that it is corrected.

Answer (score 2):

```
Document document = new Document();
// step 2

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);

 final MyEvent event = new MyEvent();

    writer.setPageEvent(event);

    document.Open();

// Add whatever content you want to add

   document.Close();

//Now Create The new class and override the onEndPage()
//I have used this for footer image but you can add wherever you want 
//in the whole page using setAbsolutePosition(see below the class)
//I am using palyFramework with java
 package controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import play.Play;

public class MyEvent extends PdfPageEventHelper{

@Override
public void onEndPage(final PdfWriter writer, final Document document) 
{
    final Font ffont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN,8, 
Font.ITALIC);
    Image img;
    try {
        final Phrase footer = new Phrase("Powered By :", ffont);
img=Image.getInstance(Files.readAllBytes(Play.application().getFile("/
                                     img- path/Image.png").toPath()));
        img.scaleToFit(60f, 40f);
           img.setAbsolutePosition(510,5);
        final PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        cb.addImage(img);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                footer,490, 15, 0);
    } catch (IOException | DocumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

It works fine for me; refer to [this link](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/page-events/page-events-headers-and-footers).

Comment: What exactly does your answer provide in addition to Bruno's answer?

Comment: Yes, @mkl I have added columnText bcoz adding the only image didn't work for me. I refer this link and added http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/page-events/page-events-headers-and-footers